# How to uv unwrap the handle of my mesh separately?

Tags: uv, edges, faces

[image][image]

[image]

I'm trying to unwrap the handle of the cup separately but the faces/edges are a bit messed up and finding hard to make a clean cut of it.

Comment: Hey :) I updated it. I'm following a tutorial and mine obviously looks different so I'm a bit stuck.

Comment: Please correct the spelling error in the title of your question.

Comment: Ah, my apologies.

Answer (score 2):

Your handle isn't entirely cut from the mug.
There are seams on only three edges, one is still connected.

Disable the Subdivision modifier to see the edges better.

*This is one of many ways to unwrap a mug handle.

Notice the seams separating it from the rest of the mug*

[image]

Comment: Disabling the subdivision helped, thanks. I was able to identify all the edges on the top part of the handle, however the bottom part, the edges are all over the place and it needs fixing, I'll post another question to show you what I mean.